# External webhook getting disabled automatically in woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, webhooks

I have woocommerce website and I want to trigger a webhook whenever products on woocommerce getting updated.

It is working fine when I setup the webhook on woocommerce advanced settings as Active status.
After sometime when am checking the webhook setup it showing Disabled and no triggers coming to webhook.

Is there anyway I can setup the webhook always "Active" in woocommerce advanced settings?

[image: woocommerce advanced settings for webhook]

Answer (score 0):

I do not have written sources to back this up, but in my experience, the webhooks get disabled when they receive for example `HTTP 500, 404,...` responses.

I've made an API to which the webhook connect, and forcefully give them always a `HTTP 200` response. In that case the webhook remains active.

Do you have any control over the URL to which the webhooks sends a message?
If yes, it might be an option to make sure it is always a `HTTP 200 OK` response that gets sent?

EDIT/ documentation of Woocommerce about webhooks, states the following:

> Webhooks are disabled after 5 retries by default if the delivery URL
> returns an unsuccessful status such as 404 or 5xx. Successful
> responses are 2xx, 301 or 302.
>
> To increase the number of retries, you can use the
> woocommerce_max_webhook_delivery_failures filter function.

https://woocommerce.com/document/webhooks/